# EF Core update untracked entity with many to many collection

Tags: entity-framework

I'm facing a problem with EF Core and collections; I have persons who read books, the books can be read by multiple people and people can read multiple books (it's a many-to-many relationship). My EF generates the 3 tables `Books`, `Persons` and `BookPersons`.

When I insert new persons with a set of books they read, there is no problem. Still when I recreate one of the persons outside the db context (so same id, but mutated collection of read books) and I try to save it, it fails on the many-to-many relation. Because the relation between the existing already exists (not unique constraint)

I've tried:

- to attach the book collection to the context (same error)
- the person (no error but no change either)
- only change person details not the collection (the untracked entity is saved but my books read is not saved)

I'm not very fond of managing the `BookPersons` table or doing queries first to get existing entities. My goal is to do an update of a person and its read books in one go. I do know how to write it in SQL but it seems EF is quite a challenge.

If you want to view my code, visit: https://github.com/CasperCBroeren/EfCollectionsProblem/blob/master/Program.cs

Thanks for explaining what I'm missing or not getting

Answer (score 0):

I would create PersonBooks model to handle that,

### Book model

```
 public class Book
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BookId")]
        public virtual ICollection<PersonBook> PersonBooks { get; set; }
    }
```

### Person Model

```
public class Person
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
        public virtual ICollection<PersonBook> PersonBooks { get; set; }
    }
```

### PersonBook Model

```
public class PersonBook
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

        public virtual Book Book  { get; set; }
    }
```

then you can get all book Id's readen by person by using

```
var personId = 15; // what ever you want
db.PersonBooks.Where(a=> a.PersonId == personId);
```

or get all persons Id's who read a book by id

```
var bookId= 11; // what ever you want
db.PersonBooks.Where(a=> a.BookId== bookId);
```

Note:
you can reach the Book entity by using for example

```
db.PersonBooks.Where(a=> a.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault().Book;
```

Comment: Thanks but this only concerns retrieval. My problem recides more on saving an updated collection

Answer (score 0):

A key factor in EF is dealing with object references. Any reference that a DbContext isn't tracking will be treated as a new entity. The `Update` method on DbSets should actually be avoided as it can lead to inefficient and potentially dangerous data changes.

This option: "to attach the book collection to the context" works with singular references, but doesn't work with collections. The trouble is that what you want to say is "add any book the person isn't already associated with" however, the DbContext has no knowledge of what books that person is already associated with unless you fetch that information first.

> ... or doing queries first to get existing entities.

This is actually what you *should* do in most cases. In the case of a simple console application to test out ideas and learn how EF works it may look like overkill, but in real-world systems this is the recommended approach for a number of reasons.

1. Keeping payloads small. Take an API or web site where you allow a user to associate books to people. Sending entire representation of people, their books, etc. back and forth between server and client can get potentially expensive in terms of data size. If I have an API that allows me to associate books to a person, if those books already reflect known data state (already exist in the db) then all I need to pass are IDs. When passing data to views the idea is to only pass what the view needs rather than entire entity graphs.
2. Keeping payloads safe. Passing entire entities around and using methods like `Update` can make your systems prone to tampering. `Update` will update *all* columns in an entity whether you expect, or allow them to change or not. By minimizing the data coming back you ensure only the expected details can change, and you by definition validate that the provided values are safe.

For example, if I have a service that wanted to update books associated to a person. In the UI I had loaded that John had "Jungle Book (ID: 1)", and I wanted to update the associations so John now had "Jungle Book" and "Tom Sawyer". While my UI might now allow it, it is certainly possible that the client browser can intercept the call to my controller / web service, and seeing a `Book { ID: 1, Name: "Jungle Book" }`, tamper with that data to send `Book { ID: 1, Name: "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy"}`. Provided you did solve this issue in a way that resulted in attaching entities and doing an `Update` or such, the consequence of this tampering would be that an attacker could rename a book. That would have a flow-on effect to every Person that referenced Book ID #1.

Instead if I want to have something like an "UpdateBooks" method that can reassign books for a person, I would have a method something like this:

```
private void UpdateBooks(int personId, params int[] bookIds)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var person = context.Persons
            .Include(x => x.Books)
            .Single(x => x.PersonId == personId);

       var existingBookIds = person.Books.Select(x => x.BookId).ToList();
       var bookIdsToAdd = bookIds.Except(existingBookIds).ToList();
       var bookIdsToRemove = existingBookIds.Except(bookIds).ToList();

       foreach(var bookId in bookIdsToRemove)
       {
           var book = person.Books.Single(x => x.BookId == bookId);
           person.Books.Remove(book);
       }
       
       if (bookIdsToAdd.Any())
       {
           var booksToAdd = context.Books
               .Where(x => bookIdsToAdd.Contains(x.BookId))
               .ToList();
           if(booksToAdd.Count != bookIdsToAdd.Count)
           {
              // Handle scenario where one or more book IDs provided weren't found.
           }
           person.Books.AddRange(booksToAdd);
      }
      
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This assumes that EF is handling PersonBooks entirely behind the scenes where PersonBook consists of just PersonId and BookId so-as Person can have a collecton of Books rather than PersonBooks.

This example runs up to two SELECT queries. One to get the Person and it's current books, and one to get any new books if any need to be added. There is no risk of tampering with books, and we can easily validate scenarios such as passing an unknown book ID. The temptation might be to avoid querying, seeing it as expensive, but in most cases EF can provide data quite quickly and efficiently. It is the exception rather than the norm that you *might* need to get creative to get around possible performance bottlenecks with data access.

3. A third consideration is to focus on keeping operations atomic, especially for things like web services / web applications. This doesn't apply when just getting familiar with the workings of EF, entities, and such, but a consideration for more real-world applications. Rather than having more complex methods like UpdateBooks(), using actions like "AddBook" and "RemoveBook" can keep operations faster and simpler. One argument for a larger method is that you might expect all of the operations to be committed (or not) as one operation, such as UpdateBooks gets called as part of one big "SavePerson" method reflecting changes to the person and all of it's associated details. In these cases having atomic actions is still recommended, except instead of updating data state, they can update server (session) state waiting for a "Save" call to come through to persist the changes as one operation, or discarding the changes. Add/Remove methods can still provide the validation checks ultimately setting things up for entities to be loaded, modified, and persisted.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I think it makes total sense how you explain it. I kind had an implementation my self which did the same thing. Still I was in doubt if it could be done faster.  

Regarding your atomic operations tip. I'm all for it but in this case I need to be atomic about the change of person and readbooks. To be honest this setup is a simplification of my real problem. This problem must save the child elements with the main items.